# Custom Enter key in mobile browsers virtual keyboard with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, mobile, virtual-keyboard

In my Angular 7 app, there is a textarea to send a message. In desktop browsers, message sending event is triggered when the user clicks enter on the keyboard. That works fine. But in mobile browsers instead of showing the default enter key, I need to replace the enter key with a `send` button. And need to capture `keyup` event of that key. I found ways to do this with Android. But, is there a way to do this with JavaScript ( or Angular)

TextArea is as follows

```
<textarea (keyup)="changeText($event)"></textarea>
```

And `changeText` function is as follows

```
changeText(event) {
    if (event.code === 'Enter' || event.code === 'NumpadEnter') {
        this.sendMessage();
      }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean on click of *that* send button the event should be triggered?

Comment: @NicholasK yes, when user clicks on `send` button. there needs to be a way to uniquely identify that event.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/ngx-material-keyboard/core) will help you.

Comment: [`event.code`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-code) doesn't have as good coverage as [`event.key`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key). Maybe that's the problem?